# Swift - Xcode not finding in app purchase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to implement a removing ads in app purchase into my application. However, whenever I test it out, it keeps telling me it has not found the product ID. I have triple checked the product ID, and it is correct. I can't seem to figure out the problem. This is what prints to the console:

Product not found: com.myCoolAwesomeApp.mjay.noAds

```
var product: SKProduct?

var productID = "com.myCoolAwesomeApp.mjay.noAds"

   func getPurchaseInfo() {

    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {

        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: NSSet(objects: self.productID) as! Set<String>)

        request.delegate = self

        request.start()


    } else {

        productDescription.text = "Please enable In App Purchases in your settings."


    }


}

func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {

    var products = response.products

    if (products.count) == 0 {


        productDescription.text = "Product not found."


    } else {


        product = products[0]
        productDescription.text = product!.localizedDescription
        buyButton.isEnabled = true


    }

    let invalids = response.invalidProductIdentifiers

    for product in invalids {

        print("Product not found: \(product)")

    }


}


func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

    for transaction in transactions {

        switch transaction.transactionState {
            case SKPaymentTransactionState.purchased:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)

                productDescription.text = "Purchase Successful"
                buyButton.isEnabled = false

                let save = UserDefaults.standard
                save.set(true, forKey: "Purchase")
                save.synchronize()

            case SKPaymentTransactionState.failed:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                productDescription.text = "Purchase Failed. Try again later."

            default:
                break

            }  
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting your productID to be a `NSSet`? It's only a string.

Answer (score -1):

I run into the exact similar problem. Here are some steps that needs to be adressed/checked after reading this technical note from Apple:

```
Create a unique App ID
Enable in-app purchasing for this App ID
Generate and install a new provisioning profile on your device
Update the bundle ID and code signing profile in Xcode
Check that your project’s .plist Bundle ID match your App ID
Complete your contract, tax, and banking Information. You need a VALID contract
```

As mentioned by the official doc there is NO need to submit binaries neither submit screenshot of in-app purchase. I have seen a lot of missleading info about this on various blogs.

After checking you have addressed each point in this list, delete your app and reinstall it.

I was basically missing two things on my side: setting up correctly my contract for ios Paid app and i didn't install the new provisioning profile on my device. May be that was your issue?